# JQuery PostMessage document.location.hash in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm using the jQuery postmessage plugin for iframe communication (for auto-resizing the parent iframe)

I have the following code:

```
     $(function () {
        var parentUrl = decodeURIComponent(document.location.hash.replace(/^#/, ''));

        function setHeight() {
            $.postMessage({ if_height: document.body.scrollHeight }, parentUrl, parent);
        };

        $(document).contents().bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () { setHeight(); });
    });
```

In IE9, document.location.hash returns an empty string and this doesn't postMessage successfully. In IE10, Chrome, and FF, document.location.hash works fine and returns a value.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: parent.document.location.href ?

Comment: it's in an iframe...can't do parent.document